# opensmile cComponentManager error

Tags: audio

I am trying to use opensmile-2.3.0. When I run the following command (I moved all files in the vad folder to config folder):

```
./SMILExtract -I example-audio/media-interpretation.wav -C config/vad_opensource.conf -csvoutput vad.csv
```

I got the error:

```
(ERROR) [1] in cComponentManager : cannot add component (instname='lstmVAD' type='cRnnProcessor'): unknown component type!!
(ERROR) [1] in cComponentManager : error during addComponent (returnVal=-1)!
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cComponentException'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I got cComponentManager error also in emobase_live4.conf file:

```
(ERROR) [1] in cComponentManager : cannot add component (instname='arousal' type='cLibsvmLiveSink'): unknown component type!!
```

What is the reason for this error? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, the folder called models is missing in opensmile folder. You should download it separately and unzip it into the opensmile folder. I found the answer here: http://records.mlab.no/2015/01/05/opensmile-the-munich-open-source-large-scale-multimedia-feature-extractor-a-tutorial-for-version-2-1/ ("....download the speech emotion recognition models and unzip them in the top-level folder of the openSMILE package")

Comment: I tried this solution, but it didn't work for me. I copied the models folder from the given link to the opensmile top directory. I still get the `unknown component type` error for `cLibsvmLiveSink` component. What's interesting is that [this] (https://www.audeering.com/research-and-open-source/files/emotion-models-0.1.0.zip) link (from the link in your answer) doesn't show the zip file to be downloaded anymore. I had downloaded it around a month back, but didn't run the example. On running it today, its showing the 404 error.

Comment: One reason for the 404 error could be that I am using version 2.3.0 of opensmile, while the tutorial on ACM-SIGMM website is for version 2.1. But you say you were able to run the emotion recognition example simply by copying the models folder for version 2.3.0 only. I wonder what am I doing wrong. :(

Comment: Do you have libsvm under src/classifiers? Maybe, I can send you the models folder.

Comment: Yes I have libsvm under src/classifiers. I tried emotion recognition with opensmile 2.1.0. Everything worked fine. Will try everything with 2.3.0 from scratch (compiling, etc). May be that will work.

Comment: Can you share the models? They removed the zip file.

Comment: Here is models folder: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dKSolpLW0Q9_uSddoOJCAGUi5g8Tjhyh